# How to stream changes from Postgres using debezium

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

**Stream changes from Postgres using debezium**

setup which is done :

1. Docker setup.
2. Started Postgres, zookeeper, kafka and then debezium connector.
3. Remote database setup with decoderbufs,wal2json(postgres).
4. connecting to debezium with curl.
5. created a watcher.

Problem : when I start watcher it is reading all the changes which is happened earlier but when any insertion done kafka is throwing an exception to debezium saying "`An exception occurred in the change event producer. This connector will be stopped.`" and in watcher none showing.

As I'm very new to these concepts, not able to figure what I missed in the environment setup and this is my first question in stack overflow please ignore my mistakes.

Main problem is it is working fine my local db.
Could any one help on this?
Thanks in advance

```
019-05-02 14:09:47,242 WARN   Postgres|kafkaserver|records-stream-producer  Closing replication stream due to db connection IO exception...   [io.debezium.connector.postgresql.RecordsStreamProducer]
2019-05-02 14:09:47,365 INFO   ||  WorkerSourceTask{id=kafka-public-connector-0} Committing offsets   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask]
2019-05-02 14:09:47,366 INFO   ||  WorkerSourceTask{id=kafka-public-connector-0} flushing 0 outstanding messages for offset commit   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask]
2019-05-02 14:09:47,375 ERROR  ||  WorkerSourceTask{id=kafka-public-connector-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask]
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: An exception ocurred in the change event producer. This connector will be stopped.
    at io.debezium.connector.base.ChangeEventQueue.throwProducerFailureIfPresent(ChangeEventQueue.java:170)
    at io.debezium.connector.base.ChangeEventQueue.poll(ChangeEventQueue.java:151)
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnectorTask.poll(PostgresConnectorTask.java:161)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.poll(WorkerSourceTask.java:245)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:221)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Database connection failed when reading from copy
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.readFromCopy(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1037)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.CopyDualImpl.readFromCopy(CopyDualImpl.java:41)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.replication.V3PGReplicationStream.receiveNextData(V3PGReplicationStream.java:155)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.replication.V3PGReplicationStream.readInternal(V3PGReplicationStream.java:124)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.replication.V3PGReplicationStream.read(V3PGReplicationStream.java:70)
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.PostgresReplicationConnection$1.read(PostgresReplicationConnection.java:251)
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.RecordsStreamProducer.streamChanges(RecordsStreamProducer.java:134)
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.RecordsStreamProducer.lambda$start$0(RecordsStreamProducer.java:120)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.receiveChar(PGStream.java:308)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processCopyResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1079)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.readFromCopy(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1035)
    ... 12 more
2019-05-02 14:09:47,387 ERROR  ||  WorkerSourceTask{id=kafka-public-connector-0} Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask]
```

- Is there any complete guide to solve this issue?
- Main goal is to,I have a db with huge data, where one
  application(producer) gets the data from another server and keeps
  all data in our own db and another application(consumer) is to get
  the store and apply business logic and for frontend. Here where I
  want to replace hits from another application(consumer) to db with
  this debezium and kafka part.
- or is there any way to do this.

Comment: Hey, your question would be much easier to read if you would format it properly. Please refer to [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: `PSQLException: Database connection failed when reading from copy` : can you validate that your database connection string in your Debezium config is correct?

Comment: thank you very much @Aaron3219 I will try to do that.

Comment: Hello @RobinMoffatt thanks for your reply, could you please help me how to do that?

Comment: Hello @RobinMoffatt, what I understand is name, username,password other details correct or not in connector? when I execute command to connect to connector using curl am able to connect to db and read the snapshot also changes which happened earlier. only problem with streaming changes, any command related to insert update delete this is causing an issue in debezium.

Comment: Is it possible your problem relates to https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DBZ-1214

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all. Above problem is solved. Actual problem with setup in remote db. There are few other dependencies which are not installed properly like postgis,protobuf-c,decoderbufs once that is properly installed problem solved.

Comment: Hi @Bhaskar How did you conclude that the problem was with the remote db setup and not the connectors configuration. I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me I checked the replication_slot size of the rds db instance and it was inactive. I used the below query to get the status of the replication_slot

```
select slot_name, pg_size_pretty(pg_xlog_location_diff(pg_current_xlog_location(),restart_lsn)) as replicationSlotLag, active from pg_replication_slots ;
```

If the actice column has a value 'f', it means it's inactive and the connector is unable to connect to the db. Since the replication slot was already inactive, I dropped it using following statement

```
select pg_drop_replication_slot('your_slot_name');
```

After that restarting the connectors resolved this error.